# Django 1.11: What fails `pickle` in my parallel test run?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, multiprocessing

I'm on a dockerized Django 1.11 and want to run my longstanding test suite parallel now:

`manage.py test mainfolder --parallel -v2`

Though it fails 2 minutes into my test suite (after all so-far run tests succeeded) with a pickle error. The stack trace however does not give me an indication where it occurs. How could I get closer to what fails it?
`tblib` is installed.

```
test_foo (myapp.some.testmodule.SomeTestCase) ... ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapp/manage.py", line 34, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 603, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(suite)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 567, in run_suite
    return runner.run(suite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 151, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/var/venv-stable/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in run
    subsuite_index, events = test_results.next(timeout=0.1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

Comment: Maybe one of your tests is returning a module (or if possible raising a module as error?) ?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this: `import foo; raise foo`. That would mess up things. The multiprocess test runner would also have trouble handling exeptions that are created at runtime like `MyModel.DoesNotExist`, but you should get a different error message if that was the case.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to get more information in the traceback in this case. If not, you can figure out which test causes this error by "divide and conquer" debugging.

Comment: By divide and conquer I could slowly identify the culprit, and it was weird, old, broken, legacy code indeed. A testcase's `__init__` had a class variable pointing to a python module for no good reason whatsoever. The test suite is running now, will see if that was the only one.

Comment: You should submit your solution as an answer and accept it. It's probably a rare bug, but it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep down I had a `__init__` method mixed into a testcase, not written by me. It stored a reference to an imported module into the class, which I don't know to whom makes sense.

```
from django.core import mail

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailTestHelperMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.mail = mail
```

Removing that fixed my problem.